# htaccess to redirect to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I've a wordpress multilanguage (2) website.
The multilanguage suddivision is:
    www.mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com/it  italian;
    www.mydomain.com/en  english.

Then, I've many domains like:
    Mydomain.net
    Mydomain.biz
    Mydomain.org
    Mydomain.it

All with dns pointing to the same ip, naked.

I wish that calling via browser the .net, .biz, .org domain it opens the english version (www.mydomain.com/en) and calling the .it domain it opens the www.mydomain.com/it.

I think it's possible managing this via htaccess but - don't know how. I tried an example found online but the result made images and css out.

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks
S.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(mydomain\.net|mydomain\.biz|mydomain\.org)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!en/) http://www.mydomain.com/en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!it/) http://www.mydomain.com/it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```